# Is $\mathrm{ZFC}^E$ outright inconsistent?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

From $\mathrm{ZFC},$ define a new theory $\mathrm{ZFC}^E$ by adjoining a constant symbol $E$ together with axioms to the effect that:

- $E$ is countable and transitive
- $(E,\in)$ is an elementarily equivalent to $(V,\in).^*$ (This is an axiom schema).

**Question.** Is $\mathrm{ZFC}^E$ outright inconsistent?

**Motivation.** The idea (or motivation) is to have a "miniature copy" of the universe available, that is nonetheless "very small" from our omniscient $V$-like perspective.

Comment: Elementary substructures are substructures such that the inclusion is an elementary equivalence. In principle it is possible that a substructure is elementarily equivalent to the whole structure but not via the inclusion...

Comment: @ZhenLin, yes but I'm a little unsure as to the implications for this question. If we assume the inclusion is an elementary equivalence, would that imply that $\aleph_1^E$ equals $\aleph_1$? If so, then the stronger version in which "elementarily equivalent" is replaced by "elementary substructure" is clearly inconsistent!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is Feferman's extension of $\sf ZFC$, and it is a conservative extension of $\sf ZFC$. But note that you cannot state that $E$ is an elementary substructure of the universe with an axiom, since that would violate Tarski's theorem. You can, however, do it one axiom at a time.

To see that the new theory is a conservative extension, note that it follows immediately from the reflection theorem: everything true in $V$, is true in a countable transitive model (well, here we apply Lowenheim-Skolem and Mostowski's collapse lemma).

I couldn't find a specific citation, but I did find several references by other people to the following paper.

> Feferman, Solomon. ["Set-Theoretical foundations of category theory"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0059148), Reports of the Midwest Category Seminar III, Lecture Notes in Mathematics Volume 106, 1969, pp 201-247.

Comment: It's not clear to me why conservativity is immediate given reflection. Could you spell out the argument a little?

Comment: Sure. You agree that everything provable by $\sf ZFC$ is provable by $\sf ZFC^E$?

Comment: Of course. The question is whether everything provable in $ZFC^E$ in the language of set theory is provable in $ZFC$ (and more importantly whether that is immediate from reflection).

Comment: Right, I just wanted to make sure we agree on the first part of the conservativity. In the other direction, suppose that $\varphi$ is provable from $\sf ZFC^E$, then it is provable from a finite subset, $\Psi$. Let $\psi$ be the conjunction of all the statements in $\Psi$ which include $E$, without loss of generality, $\Psi=\{\psi,\sigma\}$. Then $\psi$ is a sentence which (at most) says that $E$ is countable and transitive, and that some statements hold in $E$; $\sigma$ is a part of $\sf ZFC$. [...]

Comment: Now we can, with reflection (and some model theoretic tricks), $\sf ZFC$ proves that there exists $E$ which satisfies $\psi$; instantiate this quantifier and you're done.

Comment: Right, so we use the last $E$ to provide an interpretation of $\Psi$ in ZFC and we note that interpretations preserve provability and that this particular interpretation is the identity on $\phi$. That's a very minor extension of the idea I mentioned in my answer. I'd assumed you were doing something sufficiently different. In any case, I'm not sure I would call that immediate, but I guess that's a matter of opinion. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to complement your answer, in showing that $E$ *is* elementary equivalent (and give historical references). I didn't mean to snag your checkmark! :-)

Comment: No, no, I know! I was just worried I was missing some super simple reflection trick!

Answer (score 7):

As you point out in the comments, if $E$ is an elementary substructure of $V$, then the theory is inconsistent. If it were an elementary substructure, we'd have $\omega^E_1 = \omega_1$.

If $E$ is merely elementary equivalent, on the other hand, then the theory is consistent. To see this, note that for any finite list of sentences $\phi_0,...,\phi_n$, ZFC proves the existence of a countable transitive model $M$ which is elementary equivalent to $V$ with respect to those sentences. This can be established by first taking a countable Skolem Hull with respect to the subformulas of $\phi_0,...,\phi_n$ and then doing a Mostowski collapse. So ZFC can interpret arbitrarily large finite fragments of your theory, and thus it's consistent.

Comment: Hmm okay. But it looks like we've used $\mathrm{ZFC}$ to show the consistency of $\mathrm{ZFC}^E$, which can't be. Or have we merely show that *if* $\mathrm{ZFC}$ is consistent, then $\mathrm{ZFC}^E$ is also consistent?

Comment: Exactly! The theory is consistent relative to ZFC.

Comment: @user18921: This is a conservative extension of $\sf ZFC$, not merely equiconsistent with it. (Keywords: Feferman, reflection principle)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I took the "merely" to be relative to the first claim, i.e. that we've proved the consistency of the OP's theory in ZFC. But you're of course right that one can establish conservativity as well.