# Is ZFC with designated constants (m, r) forming a model of ZFC equiconsistent with ZFC?

Tags: set-theory

I have heard the results before (on this site) that $\text{ZFC}$ is equiconsistent with $\text{ZFC} + \mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC})$ as well as $\mathrm{ZFC}+ \lnot\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC})$. **This question is inspired by those results. I'm wondering a) if we construct a new theory that's like ZFC but has a model of ZFC living in its constants, is that equiconsistent with ZFC and b) is doing this kind of construction equivalent to asking about the relative consistency of $\mathrm{ZFC}+\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC})$ or is it asking a different question?**

Let's take ZFC and add two constants $m$ and $r$. The intuition behind this construction is that $(m, r) \models \mathrm{ZFC}$.

In order to nail down what $m$ and $r$ are supposed to mean, let's add new axioms to our theory constructed in the following way.

Suppose $\varphi$ is an axiom of $\mathrm{ZFC}$, let $\varphi'$ be constructed in the following way.

If $\exists x \cdots$ occurs in $\varphi$ replace it with $\exists x \mathop. x \in m \land \cdots $ in $\varphi'$.

If $x \in y$ occurs in $\varphi$ replace it with $(x, y) \in r$ in $\varphi'$.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to say that the axiom schema below is a theorem.

$$ \varphi \leftrightarrow \varphi' \;\; \text{for all parameter-free well-formed formulas $\varphi$} $$

I'd also like to be able to ask weird questions comparing $\in$ inside my constant with $\in$ outside my constant.

$$ \text{Is $\exists x \in m \mathop. \exists y \in m \mathop. x \in y \land (y, x) \in r$ mutually exclusive with the other axioms?} $$

Comment: ZFC is not equiconsistent with ZFC + Con(ZFC). (It is equiconsistent with ZFC + $\lnot$Con(ZFC), though.)

Comment: Hrm. I want to leave the mistake in since that misunderstanding is kinda important for motivating my question if you're okay with keeping the comment. Is asking whether $\mathrm{ZFC}[mr]$ is consistent (using $\mathrm{ZFC}$ in the background as usual) equivalent to asking about the equiconsistency of $\mathrm{ZFC} +  \mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC})$?

Comment: Usually $\varphi'$ is called the relativization of the formula $\varphi$ to $(m,r).$ ZFC plus the schema you propose is actually equiconsistent with ZFC. This is a consequence of the reflection theorem (which implies there are set-sized models that agree with $V$ on any finite set of formulas) combined with the fact that any contradiction must come from a finite number of axioms.

Comment: Have you seen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811042/is-mathrmzfce-outright-inconsistent or other related posts?

Comment: I have not. Thank you for the link.